# Java EE getResultList() return just object not relevant class type object

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, object, jpa, jpql

I am using this code to retrieve an object from a database. This code returns an object, but the type of that object is just `Object`.

I however want to return the type `Pcinitialdata`. As said, it returns just `Object` and the type of that is `Object`

How can I solve this?

```
String qryStrforCom = "select pci.fileNo,pci.projectNo,pci.fundId,pci.decrp,pci.devSec,pci.estBy,pci.areaCode,pci.targetDate,pci.jobnoRecedate,pci.conBy,pci.supBy,pci.ht33,pci.lt11,pci.sub11,pci.lt3Phase,pci.ltsPhase,pci.abc5w,pci.abc4w,pci.abcsecct,pci.perCapacity,pci.newCapacity,pci.proLtrToEsOn,pci.stdCost,pci.detailCost,pci.varianceNew from Pcinitialdata pci where TRIM(pci.estNo) = :value";

Query querycom = getEntityManager(webAppName).createQuery(qryStrforCom);
querycom.setParameter("value", value);
List<Pcinitialdata> listCom=querycom.getResultList();
if (listCom.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
}
return listCom;
```

Comment: Just wondering, why do you think the word is "retrive"? That's not an English word really and from the context it's pretty clear that it should be "retrieve".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query language that is used with the `createQuery` method is JPQL, not SQL.

In JPQL you can query directly for Entities, and there is no need to list all individual properties. Listing them anyway is supported, but the result is a list of separate properties and not a single entity.

Furthermore, you can enter a class type when you construct the `Query` object if you're using at least JPA 2.0 (Java EE 6). The code will then become:

```
String qryStrforCom = "select pci from Pcinitialdata pci where TRIM(pci.estNo) = :value";
TypedQuery<Pcinitialdata> querycom = getEntityManager(webAppName).createQuery(qryStrforCom, Pcinitialdata.class);
querycom.setParameter("value", value);
List<Pcinitialdata> listCom = querycom.getResultList();
if (listCom.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
}

return listCom;
```

Note that with JPA you can chain calls and oftentimes it's better to work with empty lists instead of null. It's also more convenient to declare your query upfront, [either in XML or via an annotation](http://jdevelopment.nl/put-named-queries-jpa). Finally, try to cut down on the abbreviations used and give your variables meaningful names (e.g. `value` should not be called that if it's used for the `estNo`, etc.)

Your code would then become simply:

```
return getEntityManager(webAppName)
    .createNamedQuery("Pcinitialdata.byEstNo", Pcinitialdata.class)
    .setParameter("estNo", estNo)
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appriciate it. I am new to this area and i really dnt know about JPQL. I will try this code and leave you a comment.. thanks again... :))

Comment: After spending hours , found this gem answer , +1